# Adding extra css to an existing class

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make the body height 100% when I perform a certain action and overflow:hidden as well, but only when i perform this action.

This is what i've tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.menuBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains('is-active') === true) ? this.classList.remove('is-active'): this.classList.add('is-active');
        $('nav').slideToggle();

        $('.headerBarm').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('nav').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('.headerBar').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('body').css("height:100%; overflow:hidden;");
    });

});
```

-

```
$('body').css("height:100%; overflow:hidden;");
```

I also couldn't figure out how to make it work like toggle. when i click on it again it has to go back to normal.

What i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: Use a pre-defined class, and `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't correct way to use `.css()` method, you should use this way:

```
$('body').css({height:"100%", overflow:"hidden"});
```

Also it can be more simplified as:

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    $('nav').slideToggle();
    $('.headerBarm, nav, .headerBar').toggleClass('fixed-position');
    $('body').css({height:function(){
                     return $('body').height() !== $(window).height() ? "100%" : "auto";
                  }, 
                  overflow:"hidden"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works too, I am also struggling on how to make it work like a toggle.

Comment: Position stays fixed after i click it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('body').css({
   'height' : '100%',
   'overflow':'hidden'
});
```

Comment: Its working! do you know a way to make it like a toggle.